# Space above chapter with titlesec

Tags: spacing, sectioning, chapters, titlesec

The following code gives me some space above the chapter title, that I'd like to avoid:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[frame]
  {}
  {\thechapter}
  {0pt}
  {}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0cm}{0pt}{0pt}[0pt]


\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Title}

Fancy text.

\end{document}
```

See this image:

[image]

The ellipse (added afterwards) is above the chapter title, but within the text area.

When I do the same with section instead of chapter, everything is fine:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]
  {}
  {\thesection}
  {0pt}
  {}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0cm}{0pt}{0pt}[0pt]

\begin{document}
\section{Section Title}

Fancy text.

\end{document}
```

[image: section with titlesec]

What makes `\chapter` so special in this respect? Is there a way to avoid the space above the chapter title with the package `titlesec`?

Comment: I remember having seen a similar question before and I think that egreg answered it; let me see if I can find it.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina We just have to look through all of egreg's answers :-))

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63393/4427

Comment: The given (linked question) solution does not work for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I go back the amount of `\topskip`, everything is fine:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}

% \topskip 50pt

\titleformat{\chapter}[frame]{}{\thechapter}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0cm}{-\topskip}{0pt}[0pt]

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Title}

Fancy text.

\end{document}
```

The `{-50pt}{40pt}` in the linked answer ( https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63393 ) are not the correct values for the question above.

[image]

Comment: Your question uses style `frame`, while the answer has `hang`.

Comment: @egreg fixed, thanks. Results are the same.