# Adjusting Title Spacing

Tags: spacing, chapters

I have used the patch from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160079/removing-gap-above-chapter-x-introduces-problems-with-the-text-formatting) to adjust the spacing for my chapters. What would the same code look like to adjust for sections, and subsections?

This is what I have, but it doesn't seem to be working. To be perfectly frank, I don't know what most of the code below actually does. I feel like I'm missing `section` somewhere.

To change it to subsection what else would need to be done?

```
\makeatletter
\def\@makesectionhead#1{
    %%%%\vspace*{50\p@}% %%% removed!
 {\parindent \z@ \raggedleft \normalfont \centering
 \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
 \LARGE\bfseries \@sectapp\space \thechapter
 \par\nobreak
% \vskip 12\p@
 \fi
 \interlinepenalty\@M
 \LARGE \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
% \vskip 12\p@
 }}
\def\@makessectionhead#1{%
     %%%%%\vspace*{50\p@}% %%% removed!
 {\parindent \z@ \raggedleft \centering
 \normalfont
 \interlinepenalty\@M
 \LARGE \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
% \vskip 12\p@
 }}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Please provide a self-contained example code that shows the issues.  Such a code will, by its nature, show what class you are using, what packages are being loaded, and alleviate the need for each reader to try to figure out these and other various unknowns.

Comment: Why do this the hard way instead of using something like `titlesec`?

Comment: @jpi I believe the bidi package I'm using interfere's with ``titlesec``
@StevenB.Segletes As per your suggestion I'm working on an MWE