# Remove space before nomenclature in Lyx

Tags: spacing, lyx, nomenclature

I am using Report class for my thesis and want to remove white space before nomenclature heading. I am successful in generating a PDF preview from LyX but when I import the file as LaTeX plain however the `.tex` file does not print out the nomenclature section. I do not know why this happens. I use `tocloft` package to control the spacing for Table of Contents, List of Figures and titles but I am not familiar with the command for the nomenclature section. I have changed the name of the nomenclature to List of Abbreviations. I have attached the output from the LyX file below.

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.1.4 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[12pt,english]{report}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=30mm,bmargin=22mm,lmargin=20mm,rmargin=30mm,headheight=3mm,headsep=12mm,footskip=10mm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{nomencl}
% the following is useful when we have the old nomencl.sty package
\providecommand{\printnomenclature}{\printglossary}
\providecommand{\makenomenclature}{\makeglossary}
\makenomenclature

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\AtBeginDocument{\newgeometry{hmargin=4cm}}
\raggedbottom
\pagenumbering{roman}
\geometry{textheight=245mm, textwidth=160mm, footskip=10mm}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hspace*{\fill}\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hspace*{\fill}}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hspace*{\fill}\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hspace*{\fill}}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hspace*{\fill}\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hspace*{\fill}}

\setlength\cftbeforetoctitleskip{-7mm}
\setlength\cftbeforeloftitleskip{-25mm}
\setlength\cftbeforelottitleskip{-4mm}

\setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{0mm}
\setlength\cftafterloftitleskip{0mm}
\setlength\cftafterlottitleskip{0mm}

\renewcommand\nomname{List of Abbreviations}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{\makebox[\linewidth]{List of Abbreviations}}

\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\fontsize{16}{18}\selectfont}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{-8pt}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{-12pt}
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{-12pt}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecfont{\fontsize{8}{12}\selectfont}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{-12pt}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecfont{\fontsize{8}{12}\selectfont}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsubsecskip}{-12pt}

\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\fontseries{md}\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\fontseries{md}\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecfont}{\fontseries{md}\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}

\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\fontseries{md}\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecpagefont}{\fontseries{md}\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecpagefont}{\fontseries{md}\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{15mm}{\LARGE}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0mm}{50mm}{15mm}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{15mm}{15mm}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{15mm}{15mm}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{10mm}{10mm}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{Chapter\space{\thechapter,\space\space}Section\space{\thesection}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents{}\settowidth{\nomlabelwidth}{X-Y}
\printnomenclature{}\nomenclature{X-Y}{XY}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you ultimately using (and compiling with) LyX, or are you going to export the LyX document and compile the `.tex` in a different editor?

Comment: I will export the final version as a .tex file and then make the pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Printing a nomenclature is not just as simple as adding a `\printnomenclature` command to your `.tex` file. Indeed, LyX does all the background legwork to *process* your nomenclature for printing in the PDF output. Specifically, since its nomenclatures uses [`nomencl`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nomencl), processing is achieved using [`makeindex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/makeindex).

If your intent is to use LyX for the draft construction of your document, then subsequently extracting it to a `.tex` for final processing, then you need to include the `makeindex` processing steps. Here are the steps listed in the [`nomencl` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/nomencl/nomencl.pdf) (section **2.1 The Basics**):

> The creation of the nomenclature list is very similar to the creation of an
>   index. You need to:
>
> - Put `\usepackage[<options>]{nomencl}` in the preamble of your document.
> - Put `\makenomenclature` in the preamble of your document.
> - Issue the `\nomenclature` command for each symbol you want to have included in the nomenclature list. The best place for this command is immediately after you introduce the symbol for the first time.
> - Put `\printnomenclature` at the place you want to have your nomenclature
>     list.
>
> Now put your file through LaTeX. The command `\makenomenclature`
>   will instruct LaTeX to open the nomenclature file `<filename>.nlo` corresponding
>   to your LaTeX file `<filename>.tex` and to write the information
>   from your `\nomenclature` commands to this file.

All of the above content should work as-is from your exported `.tex` file. The next steps were done internally by LyX, but you'll have to add them to your regular process:

> The next step is to invoke `makeindex`. You should instruct `makeindex`
>   to use `<filename>.nlo` as your input file, use `nomencl.ist` as your style
>   file, and write output to the file `<filename>.nls`. How to do this depends
>   on your implementation of `makeindex`. For most Unix implementations
>   you should write something like
>
> ```
> makeindex <filename>.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o <filename>.nls
> ```
>
> Now you have the file `<filename>.nls` that contains your nomenclature
>   list properly ordered. The last step is to invoke LaTeX on your master
>   file `<filename>.tex` once more. It will input your `.nls` file and process it
>   accordingly to the current options. That's all!

---

Using the example from the `nomencl` documentation, together with some ideas from [How to decrease spacing before chapter title?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63390/5764), we can remove the spacing above the (chapter) Nomenclature:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

\section*{Main equations}
\begin{equation}
a=\frac{N}{A}
\end{equation}%
\nomenclature{$a$}{The number of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature{$N$}{The number of angels per needle point}%
\nomenclature{$A$}{The area of the needle point}%
The equation $\sigma = m a$%
\nomenclature{$\sigma$}{The total mass of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature{$m$}{The mass of one angel}
follows easily.

\printnomenclature

\begingroup
\let\oldvspace\vspace
\renewcommand{\vspace}[2]{\let\vspace\oldvspace}
\printnomenclature
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

In the above example, I print the Nomenclature twice. The first time shows the default spacing above the chapter, while the second time the space (`\vspace*{50\p@}`) is removed.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able to solve this issue. When I copy paste the example given by you in the tex editor, it does not complie. There must be a way to control the nomenclature spacing in the pdf preview because if it does that, then it will do in the tex version too.