# Need to shrink space between title and top of page in customized page setup

Tags: titles, chapters

I am using a customised set-up as shown below for my title and need some help reducing the space between the top of the page and the "title" which in my case is defined by a "chapter" environment.

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
    \usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{titling}

    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

    \setlength\columnsep{50pt}
    \setlength{\droptitle}{-5pt}
    \author{The Doctor}
    \title{\textbf{Mirko Vosk EDH}}


    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \titleformat{\chapter}
      {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\fontfamily{uncl}\selectfont\filcenter}{}    {0em}{#1}

    \titleformat{\section}
      {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\fontfamily{pbk}\selectfont\color{red}\filcenter}{}{0em}{#1}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{document}
    \chapter{``Rush of the Wild" R/G \, Aggro}

    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \section*{``Base" Creatures=04}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 02 Rakdos Cackler (B/R) [2/2]
            \item 02 Kalonian Tusker (GG) [3/3]
        \end{itemize}

    \end{document}
```

I would like for the document to be one page without changing my margins and shrink the space between title and top of page. Thanks!

Comment: Since you're using `\chapter`, you can follow the instructions in [How to decrease spacing before `\chapter` title?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63390/5764)

Comment: Yes Werner, that does actually work with some modification. Just a couple of additional questions: 1) How can I reduce the spacing between that "chapter" title and the beginning of the text (or would I need to begin another request for help for that? And 2) should I "answer my own question now with a new MWE that more specifically shows what I accomplished?   Thanks!

Comment: Your MWE does not incorporate the use of `\maketitle`.  Is that intentional?  You can edit your MWE in this question any time, to replace the MWE by a more targeting one.

Comment: @MichaelDykes: Look into the `\titlespacing` command of [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
    \usepackage[margin=0.75in, showframe]{geometry}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{multicol}

    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \setlength\columnsep{50pt}
    \author{The Doctor}
    \title{\textbf{Mirko Vosk EDH}}


    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     \titleformat{\chapter}
      {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\fontfamily{uncl}\selectfont\filcenter}{} {0em}{#1}
    \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-2ex}{8ex}

    \titleformat{\section}
      {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\fontfamily{pbk}\selectfont\color{red}\filcenter}{}{0em}{#1}
    \titleformat{name=\section, numberless}
      {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\fontfamily{pbk}\selectfont\color{red}\filcenter}{}{0em}{#1}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{document}
    \chapter{``Rush of the Wild" R/G \, Aggro}

    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \section*{``Base" Creatures=04}
    \lipsum[1]
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 02 Rakdos Cackler (B/R) [2/2]
            \item 02 Kalonian Tusker (GG) [3/3]
        \end{itemize}
    \lipsum[2-4]
    \end{multicols}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: May I know what's wrong with this answer?

Comment: This seems like guesswork...

Comment: I only interpreted the question title in a sensible way, waiting for some feedback from the question author…

Comment: On the first glance, I can't see, what you have changed and why.

Comment: I  only added `lipsum`,  because the itemize alone seemed quite weird in a two-column environment.

Comment: @Bernard: That's what comments can be used for... asking for clarification.

Comment: @Jan: Oh, and w.r.t.  the O.P., I used `\titlespacing*`.

Comment: Though without the lines around the entire document and above it and all that looks fine thanks. !!!

Comment: @MichaelDykes: The lines are here to help visualise the position of the title w.r.t. the margins. For a real document, just remove the `[showframe]` option of `geometry`.