# Locally change vertical space before chapter

Tags: spacing, chapters

Is there a way to *locally* change the vertical space before the chapter number and/or tittle in a `report` document?

I already read some answers, like this one: [How to decrease spacing before chapter title?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63390/how-to-decrease-spacing-before-chapter-title)

but this make the change 'global'. I only need to adjust one chapter in my document for a tiny amount so that I can avoid a line break at the end of the page.

Comment: You could try `\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}` to achieve what you want.

Comment: Changing the vertical space before a single chapter results in *jumping chapters* and that cannot be recommended. Nevertheless most global changes can be made local if you use them inside the document. In this case you should define another kinds of `\chapter`, that does the local change (e.g. using one more parameter). This could be achieved using a group (but you should not use `\chapter` inside a group, because it would, i.e., break `\label`) or by resetting the original parameters after the internal `\chapter`.

Comment: As TeXnician wrote, there are alternatives to *jumping chapters*. Another one could be to change paragraph breaking using, e.g., `\looseness=-1` for one or more paragraphs. But without MWE I cannot show how this works.