# Remove blank space before chapter heading on top of new page

Tags: spacing, titlesec, etoolbox

I want chapters in the report class to start `3em` below the end of the previous chapter. To do this, I patch the `\chapter` command using `titlesec` and `etoolbox`.  However, this adds blank space above the chapter name even if is on the top of a new page, which I don't want. How can I remove the spacing if the chapter starts at the top of a new page?
I want the Sixth chapter heading like in the right hand side figure below, not the one at the left.

[image: Actual output and wanted output]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{titlesec}  
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}%
    {\par\vspace{\baselineskip}}{}{}
\makeatother
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0mm}{3em}{1em}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{First chapter}
\lipsum[1-4]
\chapter*{Second chapter}
\lipsum[1-2]
\chapter*{Third chapter}
\lipsum[2]
\chapter*{Fourth chapter}
\lipsum[1-3]
\chapter*{Fifth chapter}
\lipsum[2]
\chapter*{Sixth chapter}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  the command `\@makechapterhead` contains the spacing command ` \vspace*{50\p@}`.  to make this space not persist at the top of a page, patch `\@makechapterhead` to remove the `*` from the `\vspace`.

Comment: Related: [How to decrease spacing before chapter title?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63393/5764); [Adding vertical space at the start of a page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33370/5764)

Answer (score 1):

[`titlesec`](//ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) inserts the "traditional" forced `v`ertical `space` as part of setting the chapter title header. You need to also change this `\vspace*` to `\vspace` so the space is gobbled at the start of a page:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{titlesec}  
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}%
    {\par\addvspace{\baselineskip}}{}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0mm}{3em}{1em}
\patchcmd{\ttl@save@mkschap}{*}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter*{First chapter}
\lipsum[1-4]
\chapter*{Second chapter}
\lipsum[1-2]
\chapter*{Third chapter}
\lipsum[2]
\chapter*{Fourth chapter}
\lipsum[1-3]
\chapter*{Fifth chapter}
\lipsum[2]
\chapter*{Sixth chapter}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked in the MWE, but I encountered new spacing problems once I started messing with `titleformat`. Bernard's solution works even in that case, though.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to patch whatever. Just change the `class` of \chapter to `straight`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\bfseries\huge}{\thechapter}{0.4em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0mm}{3em}{1em}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{First chapter}
\lipsum[1-4]
\chapter*{Second chapter}
\lipsum[1-2]
\chapter*{Third chapter}
\lipsum[2]
\chapter*{Fourth chapter}
\lipsum[1-3]
\chapter*{Fifth chapter}
\lipsum[2]
\chapter*{Sixth chapter}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked a treat. So, I assume the `straight`removes all the formatting?

Comment: @Solstrand: In principle it only changes the fact that `\chapter` doesn't start a new page: it behaves like `\section`. However, I had an error message for some reason, which disappears  using `\titleformat`, which I made roughly like the default.  Strangely enough, doing the same for `\part` produces no error message.