# How can I rotate page completely?

Tags: rotating

I used the following codes in order to rotate my figures and title to 90 degree however I could not manage to success. My codes are;

```
\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\chapter{TOTAL ACHIEVEMENT SCORES IN QUESTIONNAIRE}

\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}

\includegraphics[width=0.4\columnwidth]{T1.png}

\end{sidewaysfigure}

I also used this code;

\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{center}

\includegraphics[width=0.4\columnwidth]{T1.png}

\end{landscape}

\end{figure}
```

However they are not working. The page seems as follows;

[image]

When I used the following codes,

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}

\chapter{TOTAL ACHIEVEMENT SCORES IN QUESTIONNAIRE}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{figure}[!htb]

\centering

\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{venus-mars-and-cupid}

\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

My title and figure seperated as shown in the image;

[image]

As far as I have seen, there is enough space to combine them. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you try inserting `\chapter{ … }` *inside* the `landscape` environment?

Comment: No, how can I do that?

Comment: Move the code for `\chapter` just after `\begin{landscape}`.

Comment: First, you don't need to use a figure environment here.  Also, you can reduce the amount of wasted space used by \chapter (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63390/how-to-decrease-spacing-before-chapter-title).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full code. Note the  page numbers  aren't rotated, and for the first page of the chapter, you have to remove it by hand:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\chapter{TOTAL ACHIEVEMENT SCORES IN QUESTIONNAIRE}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{venus-mars-and-cupid}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In this code, my figures and my title seperated. How can I fix it?

Comment: That's probably because there's not enough space on the page for both. You might try to redefine the layout of the chapter heading in this page, but the way to do it may depend on the document class.