# Spacing issues from vertical margins

Tags: spacing, margins, titlesec

I am trying to make the text in my document to align with the margins of my document. Here's a MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[top=1.0in,hmargin=1.25in,height=9.0in,letterpaper,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{12pt}

\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{12pt}{12pt}

\begin{document}    
    \doublespace
    \chapter{Chapter 1}
    \blindtext  
    \section{This is a section}
    \Blindtext
\end{document}
```

There are two issues. The first, on the first page with the chapter title, it is very far from the top margin:

[image: Chapter title spacing]
I was under the impression that using the `titlesec` package and setting the spacing as `0pt` would remove the space before, but it doesn't. I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63390/how-to-decrease-spacing-before-chapter-title) that the `report` class uses `50pt` of spacing, but using `-50pt` in the  `\titlespacing` section moves the chapter title too much. I can play with it so it gets to the line, but I am wondering if there's a proper way to do this.

Second, you can see that there is a space between the text and the bottom and top margins:

[image: Bottom and top text]

I have no idea how to remove that space from the top margin. I am less concerned about the bottom margin since one can argue that that spacing will change depending on how much text the page contains, but I am also curious if it is possible to remove that space.

**Edit:** I fixed the separation from the chapter title according to the solution given. The space between text and margin I'm talking about is this one:

[image: Vertical separation]

Is this something that can be changed?

Comment: There's no space from the bottom margin (one has to take into account descenders).

Comment: @Bernard Missed that, you're right! But I'm not that crazy about the vertical space between the text and the top margin, am I?

Comment: Maybe you wish to deal with header height, controled by `head=10pt` in `geometry` options. Also, there is `headsep`.

Comment: Make a test with `top=0in,includehead` and `top=0in` to see the behaviour.

Comment: So, what you want is to put the top of title at the top of the text area. If you use `-1.1\baselineskip` it would be almost there. But remember that there could be some glyph taller than capital letters.

Comment: This would have to be in the margin definition so that the text in all pages (not only the ones starting with chapters) would be like this right? I guess I didn't consider something may be larger as I don't think I will have that, guess I'll try my luck with the Format Comitte on this one. Appreciate the help!

Comment: I think it is not a problem to don't have the letters touching that top margin. It should contain some extra space. Think that the rectangular box containing the line contents (which contains a lot of boxes for words and letters) will be positioned exactly where you want, but the letter will be inside this rectangle, not on top of it. This is why the letters doesn't touch the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-\baselineskip}{12pt}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah! That's what I was looking for for the chapter title. But there is also that tiny vertical space between the frame and the text, which I assume is set for all pages since it looks like the same one on page 2, where there's no title. Any ideas on that?

Comment: That space is for header. See my comments on your post. You can control it. There is the `includehead` option to take it into account when set up top margin.

Comment: I think we may be talking about different things, I edited the post to include a better idea of which space I'm talking about. I set `nohead` in the geoemetry package and it did not change that space.