# Too much spacing before each new page

Tags: spacing, page

As the picture shows, at the top there is too much spacing:

[image]
I think it has to do with the following code, I already tried to change all the numbers given (.5ex etc.) but it is just the space in between Chapter I and Introduction.

Here is the preamble and part of the code I am using which I assume should be responsible for the problem:

```
%%%%Definition Partitioning%%%%
%Profondeur de la numérotation:
%Chapitre:
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\Large\color{MyBlueChapter}}
{\filright\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \huge{\color{MyBlueChapter}\thechapter}}
{.5ex}
{%\titlerule
\vspace{.5ex}%
\filright}
[\vspace{1.5ex}%
\titlerule]


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{geometry}
\newcommand{\latin}[1]{\textit{#1}}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[]{nomencl}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{float}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please provide a full minimal example instead of just a very long preamble.

Comment: Try using the [showframe] option of geometry (which is loaded twice, BTW).   You might try removing every package one at a time and see if it makes any difference.  If the document doesn't change, leave it off.

Answer (score 0):

There are not too much space. There are space needed to elegantly highlight the chapter title without use another more questionable resources as use a enormous awful font, backgrounds, rules and so on.

So the best the best solution is left that space as is.

Said that, is  you insist on removing that space:

(a) the code of your posted is of little help. It cannot be compiled, there are a lot of irrelevant packages and worse the document class is unknown. It matter if the document class is `book`, `memoir` os any other.

(b) Probably your question is a duplicate of  [How to decrease spacing before chapter title?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63390/how-to-decrease-spacing-before-chapter-title).

(b) Probably you can redefine `\@makeschapterhead` as explained in the linked question, or simply use the dirty trick of add some negative space in the chapter format, for instance some like...

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\vspace{-50pt}\bfseries ...
```

Again, assuming that you are is a document class like `book` or `report`, because that will not work if you switch to `memoir`, for instance.