# how to break line \mychapter on page but not in toc

Tags: spacing, numbering, chapters, paragraphs, white-space

how to line break this `\mychapter`?
if i use `\chapter` i can break line using `\chapter[line 1 line 2]{line 1 \\ line 2}`

```
\documentclass{report}
\newcommand{\mychapter}[2]{
    \setcounter{chapter}{#1}
    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \chapter*{#2}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#2}
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\mychapter{0}{Acknowledgments}
\mychapter{1}{Introduction}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Further Introduction}
\mychapter{2}{Experiments}
\section{Experiment One}
\section{Experiment Two}
\end{document}
```

and how remove paragraph/space above \mychapter?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example updates `\mychapter` by doing the following:

1. Store the second argument `#2` in a command called `\chaptoc`.
2. Use [`regexpatch`](//ctan.org/pkg/regexpatch)'s `\xpatchcmd*` to replace *all* occurrences of `\\` with nothing (effectively removing them)
3. Use `\chaptoc` as the addition to the ToC, while printing the original chapter title as part of `\chapter*`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{regexpatch}

\newcommand{\mychapter}[2]{%
  \setcounter{chapter}{#1}% Set chapter counter
  \setcounter{section}{0}% Reset \section counter
  \def\chaptoc{#2}%
  \xpatchcmd*{\chaptoc}{\\}{}{}{}% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
  \chapter*{#2}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\chaptoc}
}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\mychapter{0}{Acknowledgments \\ and \\ Other things}

\mychapter{1}{Introduction}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Further Introduction}

\mychapter{2}{Experiments}
\section{Experiment One}
\section{Experiment Two}

\end{document}
```

Comment: how to remove paragraph above title? any idea?

Comment: @gudanggopher: I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: i already edited my question? i mean how to remove space above/before \mychapter

Comment: @gudanggopher: See [How to decrease spacing before chapter title?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63390/5764)