# Eliminate vertical space above book chapter

Tags: spacing, titlesec, vspace

I'm trying to control the position and format of the different headings using the awesome package `titlesec`. However, I am having trouble controlling the vertical space above a `\chapter`. It always seems to add a small vertical space of approximately 4.8 mm from the top of the body.

Here is my MWE where I have disabled all spacing, with `geometry`'s `showframe` and a `\fbox` around the chapter label:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{}{\fbox{Chapter \thechapter}}{0mm}{\bf}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0mm}{0mm}{0mm}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Display of Heading Levels}

Some paragraph

\end{document}
```

[image: Vspace with chapter]

For comparison, if I comment out the line `\chapter{Display of Heading Levels}`, it perfectly aligns with the top of the document.

[image: No vertical space without chapter]

What's going on here? I have tried solutions of other question, e.g. [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63390/how-to-decrease-spacing-before-chapter-title), but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{}{Chapter \thechapter}{0mm}{\bf}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0mm}{*-3}{0mm}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Display of Heading Levels}

Some paragraph

\end{document}
```

[image: a]

"In the `⟨before-sep⟩` argument this is equivalent to `n ex` with some stretchability and a minute shrinkability" (pag. 5)  so `*-3` equal `-3ex` plus and minus some glue.

Obviously the stretch and shrink parts do not matter for a chapter, that will start a new page. It will make sense although in section or subsection.

When using `3ex` *instead of an absolute dimension,* the spacing will scale with the font size. See the numbers below.

[image: xx]

Comment: Well, yes, this works. But why shouldn't `0mm` just result in `0mm`? I have exact instructions for the spacings, and therefore it bothers me that `titlesec` doesn't use this exact height.

Comment: Do the instructions include to use `titlesec` to format the titles?  The package has defaults to format a chapter heading . They provided you a template or only specifications?

Comment: Only specifications. Would you recommend using something other than `titlesec` instead?

Comment: Each package has its hassles. If you already master `titleec`, go ahead. I personally use `memoir` to write books. It emulates many packages, so there are fewer compatibility issues. A comment: usually the chapter headings have some space before and after, plus bigger fonts. Look at different printed books.

Comment: Yes, I don't want to eliminate the space altogether, but I'm just trying to get full control of them. It is therefore very annoying that when I enter, say, `50mm` as vertical space, it actually will place it at around `54.8mm`. I will look at the `memoir` class though, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: You are not alone. See on this subject https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63393/161015