# How can I change the top margin for the \listoffigures command?

Tags: table-of-contents, margins

I'm writing my dissertation, and all of the preamble requires a heading of 2 inches; however, in the list of figures I obtain by using `\listoffigures`, the first page has the appropriate margins, but the subsequent pages do not. I have tried `\newgeometry{top = 5.08cm}` and `\restoregeometry` from the `geometry` package, but this produces a 3 inch margin on the first page of the list of figures though the rest of the pages are perfect. I'm on a really tight deadline here, and I just need it to work; I don't want to reinvent the wheel or anything, and I'll never write anything like this ever again.

Comment: As an aside: TeX knows `in`ches, so just use `\newgeometry{top=2in}` if you have to.

Comment: If you're working in the default classes, have a look at this: [How to decrease spacing before chapter title?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63390/5764) (since `\listoffigures` technically sets a `\chapter*`).

Comment: I'm using the report class, but all of the other chapters must remain the same. Is there some way I could locally change it, or change it for one part and then change it back?

Comment: So with `\listoffigures` the first page of the LoF has the appropriate spacing, but subsequent pages are too high? You want to push them lower? How many pages in your LoF?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. There are three pages total, and the second two need to be lowered by 1 inch.

Comment: In a pinch, try this: `\usepackage{afterpage}` in the preamble and then in your document: `\clearpage
\afterpage{\afterpage{\vspace*{1in}}\afterpage{\afterpage{\vspace*{1in}}}}\listoffigures`

Comment: Hmm, this did something odd. The first page is still good, the second page still needs another inch, the third page now has a margin of 2.5 inches, and an empty page was added at the end.

Comment: ...hmmm, I had an extra `\afterpage` in there. Try with `\clearpage\afterpage{\vspace*{1in}\afterpage{\vspace*{1in}}}\listoffigures`. It allows you to insert a `\vspace*` at the top of the page following the `\listoffigures` title, and the one after that. You may need to change the lengths to suit your needs, depending on what actually is inserted at the top of each page.

Comment: Yes, that worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: Technically the heading (page layout) is still 2 inches.  LaTeX just adds some space above and below the chapter titles.

Answer (score 1):

What a pity you didn't provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we could compile that showed your problem. We then might have been able to give you a definitive answer.

I did create an MWE but I won't show it, just as you didn't, as it may have had nothing to do with what you had done. However, although I'm a GOM, here is a possible answer using the `tocloft` package:

```
% reflofprob.tex  SE 611094

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{1in} % increases space before List of Figures
%\setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{-1in} % reduces space before ....
%\setlength{\cftafterloftitleskip}{} % change space after title


\begin{document}

\listoffigures

% and so on
```

Read the `tocloft` manual for more information.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entire sure why you're achieving this undesirable output, but the following can work in a pinch:

```
\usepackage{afterpage}

% ...

\clearpage% To ensure you're on the appropriate page
\afterpage{% Insert the following after the current page
  \vspace*{1in}% Add vertical space at top of page (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33370/5764)
  \afterpage{\vspace*{1in}}}% Add vertical space at top of page after the next page
\listoffigures% List of figures
```