# Reset layout position of \thebibliography

Tags: bibliographies, positioning, layout

**Background**

I have changed the position where the chapter title and subtitle are presented, namely in the center bottom of a new chapter. Unfortunately, it seems that the `\thebibliography` follows this change. Is there a way where I can reset the position of `\bibname` so that it is presented on the top left of the page?

**Code for chapter title and subtitle**

```
% Chapter style for frontmatter
\makechapterstyle{frontmatterstyle}{%
  \chapterstyle{default}
  \renewcommand{\chapterheadstart}{\pagestyle{frontheadings}\thispagestyle{frontchapter}}
  \renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\sffamily\fontsize{11}{14}\selectfont}
  \renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\chaptitlefont\MakeUppercase{\textls[60]{##1}}}
  \setlength{\beforechapskip}{-14pt}
  \setlength{\afterchapskip}{98pt}
  \renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{%
    \par\nobreak \vskip\afterchapskip\noindent\par}
}
\if@stdl@normalis
\makechapterstyle{literature}{%
  \chapterstyle{default}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\sffamily\small}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{\sffamily\small}
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge}
  \setlength{\afterchapskip}{65pt}
  \setlength{\beforechapskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\midchapskip}{0pt}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
      \node[shift={(-12mm,-20mm)}] at (current page.center)
      {%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
          \node[rotate=0,anchor=north west,inner sep=0mm] at (3mm,1.3mm)
          {
            \chapnamefont\figureversion{lining}
            \MakeUppercase{\textls*[90]{\@chapapp}\hspace{0.5em}\thechapter}
          };
        \end{tikzpicture}
      };
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
    \savebox{\@stdl@chapbox}{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[anchor=center,yshift=-45mm] at (current page.center) {
          \chaptitlefont\color{\colchapter} ##1
        }; 
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \vbox to 0pt{\vss\usebox{\@stdl@chapbox}}%
  }
  \renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{\vspace*{5pt}\par\noindent}
  \renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{%
    \par\nobreak\vskip\afterchapskip\noindent\par}
}
```

Unfortunately, I could not put together a minimal working example. If the above code cannot be modified, is it possible to modify the command `\thebibliography` to move `\bibname` so it is top left of the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: [How to decrease spacing before chapter title?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63390/how-to-decrease-spacing-before-chapter-title). It seems the title of the bibliography can be adjusted using:

```
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{40pt}
```

Comment: I am glad you found out the answer you needed! Could you tick this answer as correct if possible so that the `community` bot doesn't keep bumping it to the top of the feed every now and then please? It really helps keep clutter down, I seen on your profile you were online recently so I hope it is fine :)