# How to reduce blank space after chapter heading in report?

Tags: spacing, sectioning, chapters

Due to page restrictions, I'm trying to reduce the blank space before and after chapter title in my report. I have tried numerous methods but nothing seems to work. I have tried the solutions outlined in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63393/252049 and it reduces the space before chapter heading but I havent yet found anything that reduces the space after the heading. I also tried

```
\RenewDocumentCommand{\chapterbelowskip}{}{\vspace*{0pt}}
```

But got the error that \chapterbelowskip is undefined

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,longtable}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-8em}
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  %%%%\vspace*{50\p@}% %%% removed!
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  %%%%%\vspace*{50\p@}% %%% removed!
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\chapter{Characters}

The origin of the group determinant begins with Richard Dedekind in the late 1800's. He began to explore the idea
after studying the discriminant in a normal field [A]. He made several observations about the group determinant, but
was only able to prove some of them.

\end{document}
```

It would be great if someone is able to help me out here. Thanks!

Comment: you are adding the space as `\vskip 40\p@`

Comment: so if i delete that line, the problem will be solved?

Comment: well you have added a vertical space of 40pt and are asking why there is a space at that point, You presumably wan t_some_ space theree, but make it  whatever  value you  want.