# How to change the position of a chapter heading amd remove a single section numbering?

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, chapters, report

I am trying to minimize the 'empty' space above the chapter heading and also remove the numbering from my 'Abstract' section (both in text and in the TOC) - so not for all sections ONLY this one. Anyone got a work around here that doesn't mess with my other settings?

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[paperheight=28cm,paperwidth=22cm,tmargin=25.4mm,bmargin=25mm,lmargin=38.1mm,rmargin=25.4mm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,siunitx,pdflscape}
\usepackage{hyperref,amsmath,amssymb,graphicx,wasysym,paralist,textcomp}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lineno}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[font=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftfigpresnum{\figurename\ }
\renewcommand\cfttabpresnum{\tablename\ }
\cftsetindents{figure}{0em}{5.5em}
\cftsetindents{table}{0em}{5.5em}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\clearpage

\newpage
\chapter[CHAPTER 1: Cool Stuff]{}
\textbf{\LARGE{Some cool title}}

\section[Abstract]{ABSTRACT}
This section should NOT be numbered.

\newpage
\section[Introduction]{INTRODUCTION}
This section should be numbered again.
\end{document}
```

[image: What it looks like now]

Comment: You can use `\section*` (no optional argument), which is what `\abstract` does.  The spacing is hard coded into `\@makechapterhead` which you will need to modify, or use some package like titlesec.  Why the empty chapter title?

Comment: BTW, your image appears to be in `twocolumn`, which is implemented differently than `onecolumn`.

Comment: First question has an answer here: [How to decrease spacing before chapter title?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63390/5764)